# How did the old point contact diodes work?

Tags: diodes

I am trying to look into how the old 1N34 point contact diodes worked. They used a germanium N-type base and utilize tungsten or phosphorus bronze wire with a pulsed current to heat up the contacted area to create a small P-type region, thereby forming a P-N junction.

What I don't understand is how. Is the tungsten acting as a P-type dopant in the Ge? Then is it the tin contained in the phosphor bronze wire acting as the P-type dopant, while the phosphorus doesn't get incorporated, or instead of a PN junction was this really more of a Schottky junction?

[image]

Comment: First off, you will definitely want to read [this](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~kovar/hall.html). It's worth the time. ;) In the meantime, you should also read anything by Bardeen and/or Brattain. They cover a ***lot*** on these topics. Finally, I'd recommend reading [this](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/15353/anderson_davies_p_194808_ms_69829.pdf) paper by Anderson in late 1948. (Post-dating the 1N34 and discussing it.) It directly addresses the use of tungsten here and it gives you a datapoint from which to expand your research. Any answer here will have to incorporate it.

Comment: As a separate aside, I have personally used *galena* crystals embedded in lead with a steel 'cat whisker' to make a diode for an AM radio. I melted the lead, myself, and immersed the galena crystal into it and let it cool down. I then used a simple 'needle' made of steel as a point contact. Worked very well. This was *not* a phosphor bronze needle nor was it tungsten.

Comment: @jonk now I'm really intrigued how he actually *did* manage to solder to a Ge crystal. I mean, not a material especially well-known for its high melting point.

Comment: @MarcusMüller He probably didn't. His data shows that he basically failed. But it is a funny read and it is likely that his experience is real. It has all the elements that reflect my own experience in such things. :) I completely understood his point of view!!

Comment: it's not that I expected him to make a good (measurement-grade) contact. It's just that I really *wonder how he ended up with a solder joint*. Like, how much burning of fingers was involved? Can I have a tape containing assorted physicist cursing?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but from these sources and others, none of what I have found so far tell me the mechanisms they only talk about the results. I am interested to know what the dopants are in this case? The original galena crystals of crystal radios are a different story and are just a schottky contact.

Comment: @Barlo67 It's not difficult to find. But what exactly do you want to know? A PN junction forms ***without*** anything special, just pressing down a metal contact point (cat whisker.) A crystal diode is different ***only*** by the fact that there is a step in the process of running a few hundred mA (up to an amp, perhaps?) at either AC or DC during a short "forming" process which deepens the effect a little bit. The P-type region forms for no other reason than that electrons find it really easy to wander into the metal. The physics is of course more complex than described. But that's the gist.

Comment: @Barlo67 There were no dopants used in the 1N34. So what ***exactly*** are you looking for? I think there's some book I have, dated into the 1950's, that I could track down where this process is described in more detail. It is a thin book, maybe 200 pages or less. I remember it having a red-colored cover. It's where I learned about this as a child. Unfortunately, I've got about 5000 books in my library (most of which I've read) and it may take some time to find it. (I'm no librarian.)

Comment: @Barlo67 I just found the darned book. It's called *"Metallic Rectifiers And Crystal Diodes"*, by Theodore Conti, 1958. (It does have a red cover so my memory at my age isn't so bad, yet.) Start reading at page 2-13. It would be inappropriate for me to copy out the entire section and add it as an answer. But it confirms what I wrote above, adding a great deal more detail about the manufacturing process.

Comment: @Jonk thanks for your inputs, I will check out that book. Though pressing metal down unto a semiconductor will not form a PN junction, it will form a Schottky junction either to n-type or p-type material. Metals have no bandgap and can form a Schottky diode on a lightly doped semiconductor based on the work function of the metal and the femi-level of the semiconductor.

Comment: @jonk What is being described here with these cat whisker, 1N34, diodes is that a specific metal of tungsten or phosphorus bronze wire is brought into contact and a high current spike is used which converts an area of the surface to p-type. Where then some acceptor atoms must be diffusing into the germanium, turning a localized area to a p-type region, as per the photo. My question was are the acceptor atoms in this case tungsten and tin? Where conventionally boron is used in Ge or Si.
https://www.eeeguide.com/point-contact-diode-construction-and-working/

Comment: @Barlo67 Check out the book. That's where I got my information. The manufacturing process is, or at least appears to this reader, to be rather overly detailed. So much so that they even describe the process of purification of Ge and how impurities collect at one end, which they cut off. But that doesn't mean the author didn't miss something. That said, the author appears quite clear about how the P-region is formed. And no dopants. Also copper is mentioned there, not bronze. But since I wasn't personally in the lab pre-1946, I can't say for sure. Your link isn't all that helpful (to my eye.)

Comment: @Barlo67 By the way, on the LTspice score, Mike (who may be retired now) told me that Linear uses the ***exact same*** program that they release to the public for their own internal IC designs. (It may be that internally they include more library information, though.) Given how many different processes they have to support, I'd imagine that LTspice is pretty well vetted. So I think it is on you to work out the issues with simulation. I believe the simulator itself can be made to work properly and accurately.